# Non Linear Equation Solving with Matrices

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

Suppose I have the following matrix equalities:

A=X, B=Y

where the left-hand side matrices are numeric and the right hand side contains non-linear combinations of unknowns. Since I have quite a few variables, it would be tiresome to rewrite the equations one by one. Is there any clever way to solve the system implicitly defined above in Mathematica? Or do I have to grab each of the equations? Is there any quick way to explicitly write the equations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
A = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
X = {{x x + y y, x x - w w}, {w w - z z, y y + z z z}};
Solve[And @@@ MapThread[Equal, {A, X}, 2], Variables@X]
```

Comment: Thats something along the lines, but what if I have the same unknowns in X and Y? Would something like this work: Solve[And @@@ MapThread[Equal,{{A,X},{B,Y}},{Variables@X,Variables@Y}]

Comment: By the way, what are the chances it will solve a system of 45 variables? (numerically; I tried it here and obtained no response after running solve for about half an hour)

Comment: @user191919 Sorry, the chance depends strongly depends on your system. Impossible to say without understanding it.

Comment: Do you have any hints in solving high dimensional systems?

Comment: @user191919 If you do a cursory search at this site you'll easily find that numerical methods are too complicated to give general answers to questions like that one. Sorry.